# What is the best way to display an execution plan from SQL Server on SO?

Tags: discussion, images

What is the best way to display an execution plan from SQL Server on SO?

Answer (score 4):

Screenshot sounds fine, or ASCII if you can get away with it.

Don't do what this guy did, at any rate:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1535085/list

Still laughing about that one.

Comment: Wow... Not just a screenshot of an ASCII-diagram, but a screenshot of a *Word-mangled* ASCII-diagram...

Comment: Ah, that was what I was just looking for as a [bad] example.

Comment: Excellent example Jeff.

Comment: My first thought when I saw that was, "How'd he get Times New Roman" to show up, and then it was, "Why is that squiggly line there." And finally: /facepalm.

Answer (score 3):

I would say screen cap, or a link to a page that displays it.  If it's not an overly complicated execution plan you might also be able to just describe it or list the components in text.

Comment: A screen cap *with borders, drop-shadows, and hand-drawn circles*.

Comment: But of course.  Red circles.

Comment: Don't forget the glittering unicorns!

Comment: I don't think a screen cap would cut it- the plans can get fairly large.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about screen shots: the plans can get large.  Sql Server has an xml option for query plans.  I'd go with that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187757.aspx